# Ruby: Controlling printing in scientific notation

Tags: ruby

If I have an extremely long floating point number in Ruby such as:

```
 x = 123456789012345.to_f
```

when it is displayed, say, via `to_s`, it appears in scientific notation:

```
 "1.23456789012345e+14"
```

Is there any way to suppress the formatting in scientific notation, or on the other side of the coin, force it for extremely short floating point numbers?

Comment: Is there any way to disable scientific notation format for the whole ruby project?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can do all sorts of things using the [`%` operator](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/String.html#M000770).  For example:

```
x = 123456789012345.to_f
"%f" % x  # => "123456789012345.000000"

y = 1.23
"%E" % y # => "1.230000E+000"
```

The various options are the same as for the [sprintf](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Kernel.html#M005962) function.

Answer (score 2):

Just for convenience you can also control number of digits after decimal point. So do:

```
x = 1.234598
"%.3E" % x=> "1.235E+00"
```

Another neat thing you can do is pad with space from left like this:

```
x = 1.234 
"%10.3E" % x => " 1.234E+00"
```