# How do I get a floating point number as a string without the exponent notation?

Tags: ruby, string, floating-point, exponent

How do I get a floating point number as a string without the exponent notation, that is, a number that ends in `"e-10"` or similar? I discovered `to_s` returns the number with the exponent notation.

```
ms = 1457000.0000000002 % 1000 # => 2.3283064365386963e-10
ms.to_s                        # => "2.3283064365386963e-10"
```

I would like to get `"0.0000000002"`, but I don't get it right.

If I use my example above and evaluate `"%f" % ms`, I get `"0.000000"`, which is much different from `"0.0000000002"`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ruby: Controlling printing in scientific notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1189618/ruby-controlling-printing-in-scientific-notation)

Comment: That solution doesn't wokr for me, tho.  If  you use my example above and run "%f" % ms, you get "0.000000", which is much different than "0.0000000002".

Comment: Well, technically, it's not *much* different, but may not reflect the accuracy you want.

Comment: _"I would like to get 0.0000000002"_ – why do you want 10 decimal places and not 12 or 15 or 32?

Answer (score 2):

I think it'd still work if you specify the number of decimal places (DP) `%f`. Take your example for instance, the output is an exponent of `e-10` thus would be accurate if you specify the DP to 10. Here's a specific:

```
ms = 1457000.0000000002
secs, ms = ms.divmod(1000)
my_answer = '%.10f' % ms
```

Your output will be `=> "0.0000000002"`

Comment: Thanks.  What if I don't know the number of decimal places in advance?

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be a duplicate of this issue:

[Force Ruby to not output a float in standard form / scientific notation / exponential notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16404275/force-ruby-to-not-output-a-float-in-standard-form-scientific-notation-expone)

You can use sprintf to print the formatted number:

```
ms = 1457000.0000000002
sprintf("%.10f", ms)
 => "1457000.0000000002"
```

It's important to note that floating point numbers are not perfectly precise - so if you tell sprintf to display more digits, say 16, you will see this imprecision:

```
sprintf("%.16f", ms)
=> "1457000.0000000002328306"
```

A trick for forcing the precision is to use `to_r` to convert the value to a Rational:

```
ms = '1457000.0000000002'.to_r
=> (7285000000000001/5000000000)
sprintf("%.16f", ms)
=> "1457000.0000000002000000"
```